# Focus on the first record of listview

Tags: android, listview, focus, scrollview, record

I have a code for a listview inside a scrollview. The works ok. But when the app is started the focus is always placed in the first record of the listview.

my schema is:

- radiobutton
- Google maps
- listview

if I do not put a scrollview the listview is very small

I put the code that does it:

```
public class Helper {

public static void getListViewSize(ListView myListView) {

    ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();

    if (myListAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    //set listAdapter in loop for getting final size
    int totalHeight = 0;

    for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {

        View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    //setting listview item in adapter
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
    // print height of adapter on log
    Log.i("height of listItem:", String.valueOf(totalHeight));
}
}
```

Comment: Why on earth you have a `ListView` inside `ScrollView` ???

Comment: because I have a map of google maps and below the list of places from the database in a listview. There a better way? The problem is that if I do not put the listview, the list is too small to traverse

Comment: `ListView` has its own scroll mechanism, never ever put a `ListView` inside `ScrollView`. Just learn how to use `ListView` properly. Lot of tutorials are available on Internet.

Comment: listview can lower the screen as the scrollview?

Comment: I don't even know what does that mean, why not start with a tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: the example does not do what I want

Answer (score 1):

You can Override isEnabled(int position) method in your Adapter and return false so the focus will no longer in listview Item.

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return false;
}
```